# How do I find the middle of three numbers in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter three numbers and this program will give you the middle number : " ; read num1 ; read num2 ; read num3

if [ "$num1" -gt "$num2" ] && [ "$num1" -lt "$num3" ] || [ "$num1" -lt "$num2" ] && [ "$num1" -gt "$num3" ]; then
{
echo "The middle number is $num1"
}

elif [ "$num2" -gt "$num1" ] && [ "$num2" -lt "$num3" ] || [ "$num2" -lt "$num1" ] && [ "$num2" -gt "$num3" ]; then
{
echo "The middle number is $num2"
}

elif [ "$num3" -gt "$num1" ] && [ "$num3" -lt "$num2" ] || [ "$num3 -lt "$num1" ] && [ "$num3" -gt "$num2" ]; then
{ echo "The middle number is $num3" }

fi
```

The problem I have is with the or condition. I input the numbers 1, 2, and 3, but I get the middle number as 1 all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
getmid() {
  if (( $1 <= $2 )); then
     (( $1 >= $3 )) && { echo $1; return; }
     (( $2 <= $3 )) && { echo $2; return; }
  fi;
  if (( $1 >= $2 )); then
     (( $1 <= $3 )) && { echo $1; return; }
     (( $2 >= $3 )) && { echo $2; return; }
  fi;
  echo $3;
}

# All permutations of 1, 2 and 3 print 2.
getmid 1 2 3
getmid 2 1 3
getmid 1 3 2
getmid 3 1 2
getmid 2 3 1
getmid 3 2 1
```

Comment: It works, but the problem is that when c is 1, b is 2, and a is 3, the middle number shows up as 1

Comment: @HelloMan I fixed it up a bit. It could probably be simpler, though.

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter three numbers and this program will give you the middle number : " ; read num1 ; read num2 ; read num3;

if [ "$num1" -gt "$num2" ] && [ "$num1" -lt "$num3" ]; then
{
echo "The middle number is" $num1 ;
}

elif [ "$num1" -lt "$num2" ] && [ "$num1" -gt "$num3" ]; then
{
echo "The middle number is" $num1 ;
}

elif [ "$num2" -gt "$num1" ] && [ "$num2" -lt "$num3" ]; then
{
echo "The middle number is" $num2 ;
}
elif [ "$num2" -lt "$num1" ] && [ "$num2" -gt "$num3" ]; then
{
echo "The middle number is" $num2 ;
}

elif [ "$num3" -gt "$num1" ] && [ "$num3" -lt "$num2" ]; then
{ 
echo "The middle number is" $num3 ;
}
elif [ "$num3" -lt "$num1" ] && [ "$num3" -gt "$num2" ]; then
{
echo "The middle number is" $num3 ;
}

fi
```